# Exception using map and anonymous functions in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, exception, clojure

I was messing around with Clojure maps and I discovered this situation that I can't understand.

Let's say I got a map like this:

```
(def map-test {:name "head" :size 3})
```

I want to change the value of this map, in Clojure the usual way is to generate a new one with the modified data.

So I have this function:

```
(defn map-change
  [part]
  {:name (str (:name part) "-" 1) :size (:size part)})
```

As expected the invocation `(map-change map-test)` returns: `{:name "head-1", :size 3}`

So I wrote this function using `map` to clone the hash-map a given number of times, like this `{:name "head-1" ...}{:name "head-2" ...}{:name "head-3" ...}` etc:

```
(defn repeat-test
  [part times]
  (map #({:name (str (:name part) "-" %) :size (:size part)}) (range 1 (inc times))))
```

But I got an exception that I cannot understand when I call `(repeat-test map-test 5)`:

`Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap`

The debugger throws this exception when is assigning the value to `:size` right after has evaluated `(:size part)=>3`

Here's the last part of the stacktrace:

```
   Unhandled clojure.lang.ArityException
   Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap

                  AFn.java:  429  clojure.lang.AFn/throwArity
                  AFn.java:   28  clojure.lang.AFn/invoke
                      REPL:   80  clj-lab-00.hobbits/repeat-test/fn
                  core.clj: 2644  clojure.core/map/fn
              LazySeq.java:   40  clojure.lang.LazySeq/sval
              LazySeq.java:   49  clojure.lang.LazySeq/seq
                   RT.java:  521  clojure.lang.RT/seq
                  core.clj:  137  clojure.core/seq
            core_print.clj:   46  clojure.core/print-sequential
            core_print.clj:  153  clojure.core/fn
            core_print.clj:  153  clojure.core/fn
              MultiFn.java:  233  clojure.lang.MultiFn/invoke
                  core.clj: 3572  clojure.core/pr-on
                  core.clj: 3575  clojure.core/pr
                  core.clj: 3575  clojure.core/pr
                  AFn.java:  154  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
....
```

But if I use a non anonymous function that does the same operation as the anonymous one:

```
(defn map-change
  [part i]
  {:name (str (:name part) "-" i) :size (:size part)})

(defn repeat-test
  [part times]
  (map #(map-change part %1) (range 1 (inc times))))
```

Now calling `(repeat-test map-test 5)` works. Why ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is similar to this simplified example:

```
(map #({:a %}) [1 2 3])

clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap
```

You can expand `#({:a %})` to see what code is actually being compiled and executed:

```
(macroexpand '#({:a %}))
;;=> (fn* [p1__21110#] ({:a p1__21110#}))
```

In other words, `#({:a %})` expands to something like `(fn [x] ({:a x}))`. The problem in the body of this function is that the map is called as a function, with no arguments.

Maps behave like functions: they are functions of their keys. But they expect at least one argument and at most two:

```
({:a 1} :a) ;;=> :a
({:a 1} :b 2) ;;=> 2
```

You didn't intend to call the map as a function at all. You just wanted to have the map. The anonymous function literal always expands into a function call and cannot yield a direct value. You can solve this several ways:

- `#(-> {:a %})`
- `#(identity {:a %})`
- `#(hash-map :a %)`
- `#(do {:a %})`
- `(fn [x] {:a x})`

I prefer the latter, although I find the first one pretty funny. It's like saying: I want to return the thing I'm pointing at.

Comment: I'd add `#(do {:a %})` as an option.

Comment: So the rule of thumbs for a beginner is to use `(fn [x] ...)` and avoid the `#()` form at least until I'll understand macros better.

Comment: @OlegTheCat That's also a possibility. I added it. There are many more options: `#(and {:a %})`, `#(or {:a %})` :-). 
@Marcs I think that is a good rule of thumb. One other point to note: anonymous function literals can't be nested.